How to change request header of websocket connection from chrome extension service worker
On invoking the below function, the console message "Token rule update with new token" is logged, but when actually invoking the web-socket connection request, the request header is not updated.
Has anyone faced this issue?
I got few articles that this is chrome bug, is this fixed yet?

function updateTokenRule(token) {
  const rule = {
    id: RULE_ID_TOKEN,
    priority: 1,
    action: {
      type: "modifyHeaders",
      requestHeaders: [
        {
          header: "token-header",
          operation: "set",
          value: token,
        },
      ],
    },
    condition: {
      urlFilter: "wss://localhost:19457/",
      // resourceTypes: ["websocket"],
    },
  };

  chrome.declarativeNetRequest.updateDynamicRules(
    {
      removeRuleIds: [RULE_ID_TOKEN],
      addRules: [rule],
    },
    () => {
      if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
        console.error(chrome.runtime.lastError);
      } else {
        console.log("Token rule updated with new token:", token);
      }
    }
  );
}



You need to await for updateDynamicRules, then make the connection, example.
